# iOS: How can I grab each string from this for loop and add it into an NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have this for loop that gives me two `string`s when it is done. However I need to add these two `string`s into an `array`. The first `string` is `one` and second `string` is `two`. So at the end, my `NSMutableArray` needs to contain both `one` and `two`.

How can I perform this correctly?

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in dictArray) {
    NSString *string = ([dict valueForKey:@"string"] == [NSNull null]) ? @"" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"string"]];  
}
```

Comment: Where is your array? How did you try adding them?

Answer (score 2):

I also suggest you to simplify your code

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary* dict in dictArray) {
    id value = dict[@"string"];
    [results addObject: value == [NSNull null] ? @"" : value];
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the value for key `string` is going to be an `NSString` instance

Comment: My code is independent on `dict[@"string"]` type. I do not know what author really need to save in array - `value`or `[value description]`.

Comment: True, and +1 for the added clarity of your code. Just should point out the functional difference (and why it's pointless using `stringWithFormat:` on string instances.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need an array to add the string to:

```
NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

then you need to add the string to it, in the loop:

```
[resultArray addObject:string];
```